# Largest Consecutive Increase in Graph

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a project I am working on. The project trains images using machine learning and spits out a graph of growth vs time.

I need to detect the largest consecutive increase in my graph, then shift the starting point to the first point in the largest consecutive increase.

df is defined as:

```
df = DataFrame(totaldata[tempvideocount],columns=['Time','Embryo_Size'])
```

Here is the code so far:

```
df['is_increasing'] = df['Embryo_Size'].diff().lt(0).cumsum()
sizes=df.groupby('is_increasing')['Embroyo_Size'].transform('size')
df[sizes == sizes.max()]
```

The above code should do just that, but is giving me some errors involving the dataframes.

Python is giving me: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Then I tried to make the df an integer by: `int(df)` but it told me I need a string.

I then tried: `str(df)` and still would not let me.

The error did not make any sense, since the data is in a column.

Can someone point me in the right direction or have any ideas please?

Comment: can you include a sample of your dataframe? if you copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` into your question, this will help people reproduce your error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes of course, my apologies! And Derek it is declared like this:     df = DataFrame(totaldata[tempvideocount],columns=['Time','Embryo_Size'])